# Reading moz-icon contents from extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am writing a Firefox extension and have a need to read the contents of 'moz-icon' (e.g. `moz-icon://.img?size=16`) URI.

I have following code :

```
const Cc = Components.classes; 
const Ci = Components.interfaces; 

var iOService = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIIOService); 

var mozUri = iOService.newURI('moz-icon://.img?size=16', null, null); 
var channel = iOService.newChannelFromURI(mozUri); 
var inputStream = channel.open(), 
binaryInputStream =
    Cc["@mozilla.org/binaryinputstream;1"].createInstance(Ci["nsIBinaryInputStream"]); 

binaryInputStream.setInputStream(inputStream); 

var data = []; 
try { 
    while ((avail = binaryInputStream.available()) > 0) 
        data = data.concat(binaryInputStream.readByteArray(avail)); 
    binaryInputStream.close(); inputStream.close(); 
} catch(e) { 
}
```

It works on Windows and Mac, however doesn't work on Linux (Ubuntu 12.0 32bit). It fails when trying to create a newChannelFromURI (says it's not implemented).

Is there any other way of reading the contents of the moz-icon URI besides creating a channel out of it?

(I have posted the same question on Mozillazine and if I get an answer there, I'll update this thread and vice versa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty certain that `newChannelFromURI()` cannot throw `NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED` - this error is most likely being thrown when you try to call `channel.open()`. Reason is that not all channels support synchronous reading and reading synchronously is also generally discouraged. Also, it is easier to [get binary data using `XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data):

```js
var request = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"]
                .createInstance(Ci.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
request.open("GET", "moz-icon://.img?size=16", true);
request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

request.addEventListener("load", function(event)
{
  var arrayBuffer = request.response;
  if (arrayBuffer) {
    var data = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer));
    // Do something with the data here
  }
}, false);

request.send(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, I get the following error (trying to run it almost verbatim) : "Component is not available"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)".

Did the code you gave above work for you?

Comment: @SunilAgrawal: Heh, why didn't you quote the error message in your message? `NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE` means that icon lookup failed - Firefox doesn't know what icon to show, nothing to download for you.

Comment: I tried with the following moz-icon : 'moz-icon://stock/gtk-dialog-warning?size=dialog' and tested it in Firefox (by putting in the address bar) that it does exist.

For life of me can't figure out what am I doing wrong, now my onload doesn't get invoked at all. Definitely some issue at my end but don't know what. I have to change new XMLHttpRequest to  'Components.classes['@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest);' if that has any relevance.

Comment: @SunilAgrawal: I've changed the example to make it work in sandboxed context. In particular, I replaced `onload` by `addEventListener`. If the `load` event still doesn't fire then it likely means that the `error` event fires instead.

Comment: Thanks Wladimir, will try it out and put the resolution here. Meanwhile, I had posted the question on Mozillazine too, and they pointed to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Using_XMLHttpRequest_from_JavaScript_modules_.2F_XPCOM.C2.A0components, which could the bug I was facing.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing as to relevance, but NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED is raised for me when I do "for prop in object"  where the object is a mouse event. The error is raised in the "object[prop]" expression for the non-existent properties "end" and "windowHref" that are generated by the "for/in".